# VSCode auto import - how to force Material-UI full path import

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, material-ui

When using VSCode's auto import feature to import Material-UI components, it will use a named import to import from the top-level file:

```
import { Button } from "@material-ui/core"
```

However, I would like the auto import to use the [full path import](https://material-ui.com/guides/minimizing-bundle-size/#option-1) instead:

```
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button
```

I've tried to find a way to configure VSCode's auto import to do this to no avail.

Does anyone know if this is possible / how to configure this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can change the type of material UI import in vscode by installing `material-ui-snippets`. You can follow the instruction [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscodeshift.material-ui-snippets)

go to the extension setting, first check the `Material-ui-snippets: Add Completion Imports` and then change the type of `Material-ui-snippets: Import Paths` according to you preference. (In your case, it would be `second level`)

**Import Paths**

- auto - uses top level if other top level imports are found, second
  level otherwise
- top level - import { Button } from '@material-ui/core'
- second level - import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button'

**Edit:**
The above extension is valid for MUI 4.
The docs for this extension suggests using [mui-snippets](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscodeshift.mui-snippets) for MUI 5.

Comment: Does not work for me