# Prefer modular auto imports over destructuring in vscode auto imports react

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

I am trying to get auto imports like this in vscode

`import Button from '@mui/material/Button'`

instead of:

`import {Button} from '@mui/material'`

because as you might know, the second one slows down vscode.

[image: Button auto import]

Here you can see it is auto importing it, but making a destructuring of @mui/material

Comment: have you found an answer to this yet?

Comment: Nope, no solution, just manually changing it. I would appreaciate an upvote

Comment: Did you try this one: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=steoates.autoimport ?

Comment: I couldn't flag the question because there is a bounty but I think it's a duplicate of this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66463620/vscode-auto-import-how-to-force-material-ui-full-path-import

Comment: My question is about all imports not just material ui