# How to use path imports in VSCode for MUI components?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, material-ui

This question is answered here: [VSCode auto import - how to force Material-UI full path import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66463620/vscode-auto-import-how-to-force-material-ui-full-path-import)

However, using the extension and configuring it to use second level imports does not work for me. I am using MUI 5, so I am using this extension: https://github.com/vscodeshift/mui-snippets

Anyone knows how to force the full path import on Material UI?